# Count item it partial view in View of asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have one view in my asp.net mvc project :

```
 <div id="featured">
       <% Html.RenderPartial("../Shared/UserControls/RelatedProduct", Model.ProductDetail); %>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult ProductSpec(int id, int dep, int cat, int tab)
 {
    var pvc = new CMSViewModel()
    {
       ItemDetail = new ProductVM()
       {
          GetItemReference = DataContext.GetItemReferences()
       }
    };
    return View(pvc);
}
```

This is my partial view :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Web.ModelView.ProductVM>" %>
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <%        
        for(int i=0; i<(Model.GetItemReference.Count());i++) {
           //list all item from model
        } 
    %>
    </ul>
```

The problem : When the item in partial view is empty, View will be blank.
I want to count the partial view item in View, So if it blank, I will replace it with the other Null Image.

Could any one tell me how could I count the item in the partial view in View.

Answer (score 2):

**In short:** It would be a good idea to check for the availability of elements in your collection before rendering them. The right `System.Linq` method for that is `.Any()`.

Here is a sample that demonstrate the concept:

```
 <%     
    if(Model.GetItemReference.Any())
    {
       // Render your content
        for(int i=0; i<(Model.GetItemReference.Count());i++) {
           //list all item from model
        }
     }
    else {
     //
     // Render your content when NO Items
    } 
    %>
```

Comment: ElYusubov, But I also want to change something in the View when the items in partial view empty.

Comment: You may introduce a conditional property in your ViewModel, that may solve this issue for you. or you may also use js to accomplish this.

Comment: ElYusubov, What do you mean `conditional property in ViewModel` ?